# What text(s) do modern scholars use to translate the New Testament?

Tags: textual-criticism, translation-philosophy, manuscript

It is common for most Pastors like myself to us the 'original Greek' when studying in preparation for teachings and sermons. I am curious, though, as to how we came to understand what the original Greek is.

Comment: This is really quite broad. Please see our tag [tag:textual-criticism].

Comment: Related: http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/923/strongs-is-a-concordance-not-a-lexicon
http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/639/what-good-reference-works-on-biblical-studies-are-available-freely-online/642#642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most used is the united bible societies text. It is based on many early manuscripts, with footnotes showing details on passages where the earliest and best manuscripts don't quite agree. Modern editions are all about the same, since the earliest manuscripts have been available in editions and photographic facsimiles for decades.

Answer (score 1):

It's still an open question, as we still don't know for certain what the "original" Greek actually was (nor probably ever will).  There are [several hundred different manuscripts](http://bibletranslation.ws/manu.html) available.  These manuscripts are sometimes classified according to their ["text type"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categories_of_New_Testament_manuscripts) (e.g. "Alexandrian", "Western", "Byzantine", etc.).

The most popular Greek text among Protestants I believe is the so called "Critical Text", [published by the United Bible Society](http://bibletranslation.ws/manu.html).  Probably of most interest to you would be the [Greek-English version](http://amzn.to/2cLBtKU), which has the Critical Text on one page, the RSV translation on the facing page, and details about all the alternate Greek readings in footnote. (There is apparently a newer version with the NIV on the facing pages, but the NIV is such a free translation it doesn't seem very suitable to follow along the Greek with).

The **Critical Text (CT)** is "Critical" because a great number of scholars examined all the manuscripts available and made a decision on what manuscript to use for each verse or verse part.  A separate book called [*A Textual Commentary on the Greek New Testament*](http://amzn.to/2cLAhr9) details every single decision and explains what factors went into making it (it's actually quite interesting!).  The CT does not always use the oldest known manuscript in its selections.

Two additional Greek Texts that are available are:

- The **1550 [Textus Receptus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textus_Receptus) (TR)**, which is the text upon which the King James Version is based
- **The [Majority Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_text-type) (M)**, based on what the majority of manuscripts say any given verse should be.

The New King James Version translation uses the Textus Receptus, but footnotes each verse where there is a different Greek reading in the CT or M.

As far as I know, almost all of the New Testament translations (save the versions I describe below) are based on these manuscripts.  The only exception that comes to mind is the NIV, which uses what they call an "eclectic" text, that picks and chooses from everything available.

Finally, there is the **1904 Patriarchal Text (PT)** of the Ecumenical Patriarchate of Constantinople.

As strange as it may sound, all the churches in Greece and many in Asia/Asia Minor that we read about in the Acts of the Apostles still actually exist and are today part of the Eastern Orthodox Church (they are not aligned with the Roman Catholic Church).  The Patriarchal Text was compiled in order to harmonize all of the different Greek texts that were used in the various churches and monasteries in the territories that used to be part of the Byzantine empire.  It ends up being very close to the Majority Text.

The PT is available online from the [Greek Orthodox Archdiocese of America](http://www.goarch.org/chapel/biblegreek).  It is also the basis for the [*Orthodox New Testament*](http://amzn.to/2clTodd) and the [*Eastern Orthodox Bible: New Testament*](http://amzn.to/2cziMuR), but NOT for the New Testament in the [*Orthodox Study Bible*](http://amzn.to/2c1DxkV) (which uses the NKJV, and therefore the TR).

Comment: You have made it a bit too simple. There are currently 5 different patriarchs of (for example) Antioch: 3 head churches in communion with Rome, 1 is in communion with Constantinople, 1 heads the Syrian Orthodox (monophysite) church.

Comment: Yes, succession is contended in Antioch and Alexandria due to the fallout from ancient schisms.  For that reason I wrote "many" in regards to Asia/Asia Minor.

Comment: Almost all modern translations are the eclectic and judge for themselves which variants are most likely. The NIV team is just the only one which has published the Greek text underlying their translation.